# The screen on my Pixio gaming monitor is distorted as soon as I power it on

Tags: display, gaming

[image: picture]
Distorted picture on Pixio gaming monitor

Comment: That looks a lot like someone punched the screen. A drop generally would have a less... large area of damage, and your panel is basically toast.

Comment: Is this a new monitor? Was it like this when you unpackaged it? If so ask for your money from the seller.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to have suffered a large frontal impact.

It's smashed.

I'm kind of surprised you can't see that from right in front of the screen, even with it switched off.

[image]

Comment: "Its dead, its an ex monitor, its pining for the fjords..."

Comment: "…shufflled off 'is mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleedin' choir invisible…" Perhaps it happened when someone was trying to nail it to its perch?

Comment: *Technically* you could replace the panel, bit IIRC Pixio's a budget brand, and that might not be economical